# Save draggable div's position to localstorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, local-storage

I'm rewriting my code that allowed a user to drag a div on iOS so that it is cleaner, and one of the changes I am hoping to implement is using `localstorage` to save and retrieve the position of each of these div's.

jQuery:

```
$(".drag").each(function () {
    var drag = this;
    xPos = drag.offsetWidth / 2;
    yPos = drag.offsetHeight / 2;
    drag.addEventListener("touchmove", function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).css({
            "left" : event.targetTouches[0].pageX - xPos + "px", 
            "top" : event.targetTouches[0].pageY - yPos + "px",
            "z-index" : "101",
        });
        $("div").not(this).css("z-index", "100");
    });
});
```

Before, I had set the position by using a cookie:

```
$(window).unload(function () {
    $(".remember").each(function () {
        $.cookie(this.id, this.value, {
            expires: 365
        });
    });
    $(".draggable").each(function () {
        var a = $(this);
        $.cookie(this.id, a.css("top") + "_" + a.css("left"), {
            expires: 365
        });
        $.cookie("disp" + this.id, a.css("display"), {
            expires: 365
        });
    });
});
```

Each div that was draggable had a `.draggable` class on it, and if I wanted to save the value of a text box, it had a `.remember` class on it.

Is it worthwhile/practical updating it to use `LocalStorage`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Localstorage is much better place for this, than cookie. Because you will not send additional bytes to server with each request and so on.
Just keep in mind that most problems with cookies remain with transition to localStorage - scripts from multiple tabs and same domain can mess up with your stored data, but i assume its your own site without third party includes, that you should worry about.

Comment: Have you worked with localstorage? I know the comments are for the post itself, but I have made progess since I posted my question and I'd like your input.

Comment: Yes. Its handy for small things, like ui settings or game top scores. But for bigger stuff - you might want to read these articles: http://my.opera.com/c69/blog/2012/03/11/localstorage-fud  _p.s: year ago i was able to crash Chrome tabs consistently with storing images in localStorage, but now (maybe) situation have changed._